# Certificate Authority - what is the significance of having a CA in a client/server model or any networked system?

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority

I am kind of understanding what a CA is, and have seen it used in many places, but am still having trouble grasping its purpose. Can anyone explain it to me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without a trusted CA, the client has no way of knowing that the server is who it claims to be.

Answer (score 0):

With a CA, the client has to trust something which may fail, probably silently, and if it does the certificate can be forged without the client knowing. Without a CA the client trusts certificates that they actually trust, or that are trusted by people the client trusts, and not by a company that the client is forced to trust, and there is no way short of breaking the cryptosystem for a different certificate to be presented without the client knowing it.